# tun0+ iptables rule

Tags: iptables, firewall

I'm trying to figure out what that + sign means in a rule such as this:

```
-A FORWARD -i tun0+ -j ACCEPT
```

I'm pretty positive it relates to vpn. I noticed a /dev/net/tun interface and a tun0 in ifconfig, but for the sake of thoroughness, I want to know about that + sign. Anyone know anything?

Comment: Ok, so it seems that the + is a wildcard that is mentioned under the spec of the -i flag. hmmm now to figure out why.

Comment: Is that really `tun0+`, and not `tun+`? As far as I know `tun0+` would only match `tun0` anyway, whereas `tun+` would match `tun0`, `tun1`, `tun2`, …

Comment: Yes it is, that's why I'm stumped. In the server config for openvpn, it is "dev tun0", so would openvpn create tun01 tun02 etc... for concurrent vpn connections?

Comment: `dev tun0` will force creation of `tun0` device. If you want to dynamically create `tun` devices and don't care which server uses which device, then use `dev tun` so `tun0`, `tun1`, `tun2`, ... be created subsequently and `tun+` in iptables rules will match all of them.

Comment: @Realn0whereman: Where did you find this rule anyway?

Comment: @forcefsck Why does dev tun create tun0, tun1, etc... but dev tun0 does not create tun01 tun02 ? Does the configuration look for dev _stringWithoutIntegerSuffix_ and then create dynamic devices?

Comment: @Realn0whereman, yes, `dev tun` is interpreted as _dynamically create a tun device with the first available suffix_. `dev tun0` is interpreted as _create tun0_. You will find out that, generally, devices don't have a zero padded suffix. So, is `tun11` the second of the second tun or the eleventh?

Comment: @Realn0whereman If you are satisfied with an answer, you can accept it by clicking the green pipe on the left side. This is a big reward to the answering person.

Answer (score 6):

From [here](https://www.webhostinglogic.com/support/support-topics/ipchains-and-iptables.html): *To match all interfaces of a type, use the plus sign such as eth+*.

And yes, the "`+`" sign means here just as "`*`" in pattern matching or "`.*`" in regexps.

This rule is false, the `+` is unneeded, although it does not harm (because a tunnel named `tun01` or `tun05` are very unlikely). The developer of this script wanted to write probably only `tun+`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it does work for all ip blocks in that interface. It means, if you have `tun0`, `tun0:0`, and `tun0:1` and you need to manage all, you will probably want to write `tun0+` there.

Answer (score 0):

Using "tun+" instead of just "tun0" makes perfect sense if you are running several instances of, for example, OpenVPN on the same server. The multiple instances will create multiple devices called tun0, tun1, tun2, etc. and all of their traffic has to pass through the firewall (and has to be properly forwarded).